# Passing Object of SuperClass to the SubClass Constructor in Python

Tags: python, oop, object, inheritance

```
class super(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.abc = kwargs.pop('abc', None)
        self.xyz = kwargs.pop('xyz', None)

class sub(super):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pqr = kwargs.pop('pqr', None)
        self.sty = kwargs.pop('sty', None)

obj_super = super(abc=abc, xyz=xyz)
obj_sub = sub(obj_super, pqr=pqr, sty=sty)
```

I want to access the attribute values set for object `obj_super` via `obj_sub`.
Something like:  `obj_sub.obj_super.abc`

Comment: The first letter of class name is usually written as capital. Also, you shouldn't name your classes like a built-in method, e.g. super.

Comment: As you have inherited the ```Super``` class in ```Sub``` class, the Super class attributes can be accessed from Sub class using ```obj_sub.abc``` I think you should refer [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) or refer some online tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
class super(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.abc = kwargs.pop('abc', None)
        self.xyz = kwargs.pop('xyz', None)
        
    
    
        

class sub(super):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pqr = kwargs.pop('pqr', None)
        self.sty = kwargs.pop('sty', None)
        self.contain = args[0]

    
    

obj_super = super(abc=1, xyz = 2)

obj_sub = sub(obj_super, pqr =3, sty=4)
print(obj_sub.contain.abc)
```